# Can Display Suite render content without my theme around it?

Tags: 7, display-suite, javascript

I'm just getting familiar with [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) and I want to know if I can use it to display only the content - not my header/footer/etc from my theme.

My goal is to display this content in a modal popup so I don't want anything around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aDisplay suite should allow you to modify the output for the fields and even choose some layouts but AFAIK it won't let you completely omit the site theme (i.e. create a page without header or footer).

You can use js/ajax to grab just the portion of the page you want to appear in the modal pop-up so that it doesn't pull in the header/footer. Depending on the JS library(ies) you are using this could be easy or challenging.